# Let's remove [tag:math]!

Tags: discussion, tags

[math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) is incredibly broad.  Its [description](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) says:

> The challenge involves mathematics. Also consider using more specific tags: [number] [number-theory] [arithmetic] [combinatorics] [graphs] [geometry] [field-theory].

After going through the tag, there seem to be three distinct types of questions tagged with [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math):

1. Those that deal with a particular field in math, such as [combinatorics](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics), [prime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prime), or [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry)
2. Those that deal with basic math and [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic).
3. Those that include math, but the math is not the focus of the challenge.

Is [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) a problem, and if so, how should we deal with it?

Comment: I don't see how or why this could possibly be an issue...

Comment: It's *so* broad, and undescriptive.

Comment: @NathanMerrill It's a catch-all for the various math problems that don't fit into one of the existing tags and don't need a tag made for them. It's like [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: @Mego Care to provide examples?  I looked through a good deal of them, and I didn't see any of them that didn't within another math-related tag.

Comment: @Mego You seem to be assuming that having a catch-all tag is a good thing. For challenge types, which should all be disjoint, that makes sense, so we can cover one-off challenge ideas, but I'm not sure it's a good thing for topics. It just means you have to think less hard about how to choose meaningful tags. "Uh, what tags should I use, I don't know, ah [tag:math] fits, nice I'm done." Seeing how broad it is, it's also virtually useless for filtering, so I really don't see any benefit in having the tag.

Comment: @MartinBüttner The alternative is making a new tag every time a challenge about a new math-related topic is posted, which I think is far less preferable.

Comment: @Mego There really aren't that many "fields" in math we haven't already covered with our tags.  That said, even if there was a question that was in an obscure field of math, adding the tag [tag:math] doesn't make it easier to find.

Comment: I'm agreeing with Alex here - I think this is a non-issue that you're trying to make into an issue.

Comment: @Mego perhaps its not a problem, but that doesn't mean we can't make the site better.

Comment: I agree with Alex's other point, too - I don't think removing it would benefit the site in any substantial way.

Comment: In the words of Finn from *Adventure Time*... "math that!"

Answer (score 25):

## Let's keep it.

Though it encompasses a wide variety of challenges, I do think it adds a level of context not readily available with separate tags like [number-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic), or what have you.

Consider this (admittedly contrived) scenario. Say a user is thinking, "I'd like to participate in a mathy challenge but I don't have a particular type of math in mind." If there was no way to say "math only, pls" then they have to search through a huge number of tags and would likely overlook some interesting challenges that involved a different kind of math. As it stands, they can just say, "find me [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math)" and they'll be able to explore a lot more challenges.

Further, I fail to see any actual *benefit* to removing the tag. So what if it's broad and encompasses many challenges? It's typically used in conjunction with more specific tags, which seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: In your scenario, the problem is that pretty much *every* challenge involves math.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I disagree. Though a lot of challenges do involve some degree of math, I think the tag is more saying "this is *about* math," not "this will require a bit of math." We have [string], [ascii-art], [file-system], and all kinds of other things.

Comment: So would you argue we remove [tag:math] from challenges that require math, but aren't *about* math?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Do you have any examples of challenges that require some degree of math and aren't about math but bear the [math] tag?

Comment: [The top question from the tag](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48476/programming-languages-through-the-years)

Comment: @NathanMerrill Computing the GCD is one of the subtasks of that challenge so I'd argue that it's relevant in that case.

Comment: I personally disagree, but here are 5 [more](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67138/hexadecimal-and-the-alphabet) [from](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30292/knot-or-not) [the](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23423/mandelbrot-image-in-every-language) [first](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54224/world-big-dosa) [page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/68866/superstitious-hotel-elevator).

Comment: @NathanMerrill, "knot or not" is one of the most mathematical questions on the entire site, and is probably a good argument for having a [tag:math] tag, because [tag:topology] isn't going to have many questions at all. "Mandelbrot image" is also clearly mathematical.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree that they are all mathematical.  The entire *site* is mathematical, which is why [tag:math] should be broken down.  Whether or not "Knot or Not" goes in a [tag:topology] tag, or some other tag, I don't really care, but as it stands, *everything* fits under math.

Comment: @NathanMerrill [tag:quine], [tag:hello-world], [tag:string], and [tag:kolmogrov-complexity] are several examples of subjects that are not inherently mathy.

Comment: I'm not arguing that every tag is mathy, but that every question on this site is mathy.  [tag:kolmogrov-complexity] and [tag:quine] absolutely do have to with math.

Answer (score -14):

## Yes, it should be removed.

The steps to fix should be:

1. Go through each of the tagged questions, remove [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math), and add the particular field it is in.
2. If math isn't the focus of the challenge, the simply remove the tag.
3. Make [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) a synonym for [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)

Comment: Certainly [tag:math] ≠ [tag:arithmetic]

Comment: Um, your saying math is too broad, and your solution is to make a bunch of tags that can be summed up as Mathematics or math, so I don't see this issue

Comment: @GenericUser He's saying that rather than tagging things [math], we should use tags more specific to the type of math, e.g. [geometry], [number-theory], etc.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't seem necessary. I don't look at a math question assume it's only about arithmetic. The subject isn't too broad. Tags should be specific, but not to the point of one for every detail of a subject. It would confusing to have questions with 12 or so tags, but it seems since there's been so recent new tags, some are starting to try and do that.